# Prove that if characteristic function is absolutely integrable then corresponding density function will be uniformly continuous.

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-continuity, characteristic-functions

So the point is that you obtain density function through the characteristic function with the inversion formulas. That's the part of the task. Then it supposed to be uniformly continuous.

That is, if $\phi(t)$ is absolutely inegrable, show that $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int \phi(t) e^{-itx} dt$ is unformly continuous.

I have got the exercise in my book, I’ve tried and it led to nothing as follows:
$|p_\xi(x)-p_\xi(y)| \leq \frac{1}{
2\pi}|x -y|\int |t \phi_\xi(t)| dt$.
If the last integral was without $t$ then it would be it. But it contains $t$ and may not converge since that.
I’ve been stuck on this for a few days, please, help.

Comment: Take something like $p(x)=\varphi(x)\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}}(x)+|x|\mathbf{1}_{\mathbb{Z}}(x)$ where $\varphi$ is the standard Gaussian density. Then $\phi(t)=\int_\mathbb{R} e^{ixt}p(x)dx=\int_{\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}} e^{ixt}p(x)dx=e^{-t^2/2}$ is absolutely integrable, but $p$ is not even continuous.

Comment: @Snoop I see what you say, that works, but let us assume that the density function is given by the inversion formulas (meaning you are given the characteristic function and then you reconstruct the corresponding density). That makes your counter-example impossible. Can you help with that?

Comment: Alright, so if I understand correctly the question is: is $p(x):=(2\pi)^{-1}\int\phi(t)e^{-itx}dt$ uniformly continuous?

Comment: @Snoop yes, under the condition that $\phi$ is absolutely integrable. I have added this to the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you noticed, it would be great if $\int |t \phi_\xi(t)| dt$ was finite. Under the assumptions of the question, it is not the case. But $t\mapsto t\phi(t)$ is locally integrable.

Take a positive $\varepsilon$. Since $\phi$ is integrable, we can find $R$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-R,R]}\lvert\phi(t)\rvert dt<2\pi\varepsilon$. Denoting $$f(x):=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int \phi(t) e^{-itx} dt,$$
one has for each $x,y\in\mathbb R$:
$$
\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert\leqslant 2\varepsilon+\frac 1{2\pi}\left\lvert\int_{-R}^R\phi(t)\left(e^{-itx}-e^{-ity} \right)dt  \right\rvert\leqslant 2\varepsilon+\frac{R^2}{\pi}\lvert x-y\rvert.
$$

Comment: I was a bit confused, I made some comment here, I already have deleted it, nevermind. Thank you so much!

Comment: but I gues that in $\frac{R}{\pi} |x- y|$ you've missed some stuff, but that doesn't matter, still I got it

Comment: Probably a square, since we bound $\int_{-R}^R\lvert \phi(t)\rvert |t| dt$ by $2\int_0^R t dt=R^2$. Otherwise I think that it is fine.