# Characteristic functions: upper bound on |phi(t)e^(-itx)|

Tags: probability-theory, uniform-continuity, characteristic-functions

[This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4841216/348586) about characteristic functions asks about absolutely integrable $\phi(t)$. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4841216/348586) mentions "we can find $R$ such that $\int_{\mathbb R\setminus[-R,R]}\lvert\phi(t)\rvert dt<2\pi\varepsilon$".

The argument I don't get is how $\frac 1{2\pi}\left\lvert\int_{-R}^R\phi(t)\left(e^{-itx}-e^{-ity} \right)dt\right\rvert \leqslant \frac{R^2}{\pi}\lvert x-y\rvert$; **in particular, the $|x - y|$ bit**. It seems to me that $|e ^ {-itx} - e ^ {-ity}|$ gets upper-bounded by $|-tx - (-t)y| = |t||x - y|$. Why is that?

Or, $|e ^ {-i\theta}| = 1$, so if you only deal with $\int_{-R}^{R} |\phi(t)||t| \mathrm{d}t$ (in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4840980/prove-that-if-characteristic-function-is-absolutely-integrable-then-correspondin#comment10311621_4841216)), where does the $|x - y|$ come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|e^{-itx}-e^{-ity}|=|-it \int_x^{y} e^{-its}ds|\le |t||\int_x^{y} 1ds|=|t| |x-y|$.